# Zram decompression failed with new kernels

Tags: bug-reporting

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with HWE kernel.

When I used zram, I've got read errors, then I read kernel log and seen: zram: Decompression failed!

I noticed it after upgrade kernel from 5.4.0-48 to 5.4.0-54 (now it is latest version). I tried to use zstd and lz4 algorithms, same problem. So, I decided to test on -48 version, and with this kernel (5.4.0-48) all working without errors!
After that, i tried every newer kernel: right after 48 coming 51 version and this kernel is "bugged" too as and 54.

Ubuntu 20.04 supplied with 5.4.0-54 kernel too, so I tested it and what I've got? Same problem! Decompression error.

Error is happening not from start, it comes after some time (maybe 1 hour, maybe 2 days).

Also, I tested this bug with three different PCs with good condition (no memory errors, etc) and there's same problem, that going away with -48 kernel.

Same problem with 5.4.0-58:

```
badblocks -sv /dev/zram7 
Checking blocks 0 to 31457279
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 err16828216done, 0:03 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
16828217
16828218
16828219
17032356
17032357
17032358
17032359
done                                                 
Pass completed, 8 bad blocks found. (8/0/0 errors)
```

Comment: Is it just the change in logging level for the error from alert to warning?? See commit 4e79603bbd33. Otherwise you might need to bisect the kernel to isolate the exact commit.

Comment: Suggest that, just for a test, you try [kernel 5.10-rc5](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10-rc5/). It has a locking order fix, commit 0669d2b265d0

Comment: @Doug Smythies
This is not just a warning, zram really becoming unreadable! You can scan it using badblocks and you'll see badblocks on zram device.

Comment: 5.4.0-59 errors too

Comment: @JmAbuDabi Yes! Was fixed in 5.4.0-56 and now again...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by cpu of the device. This is [apparently a known bug](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/16056-problems-with-zram-on-h235-boards-zram-decompression-failed-err-22/) for arm cpu, and on an 18.04 Intel i5 it works, but on an Intel core duo T5250 it no longer works, both with same kernel and settings. Only solution would be to test preproduction kernels in hope they fix it for obscure hardware.

Comment: And what about just use -48 kernel and do not upgrade?